# how can get queryParams from url

Tags: ember.js, query-string

`Url:192.168.0.40/index.html?code1=123#/cases/?code2=4567`

How can get Code1 and Code2 from url?

My Code

```
App.CasesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

    model: function(params) {  
        var code1=params.queryParams.code1;
        var code1=params.queryParams.code2;
    }
})
```

I can get code2 but code1 is undefined?
`this.store` is null

please help me

Comment: Are you sure you get `code2`? I'd expect only `code1` to be set, since the hash probably wouldn't be submitted as part of the request query. Unless there's something special I'm missing right now.

Comment: Should be `params.code1` but before you need specify that you route has query params. [here](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/routing/query-params/) more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can get `code2`, I will assume you are using the *Router* with `location` property set to `hash`, which means the `code1` query parameter is not parsed by the Ember application.

You can however parse the global `location.search`, which will work.

Getting a query parameter value is explained here: [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)